# Why the k8s rollback (rollout undo) is not working?

Tags: kubernetes

After a successful

`kubectl rollout restart deployment/foo`

the

`kubectl rollout undo deployment/foo`

or

`kubectl rollout undo deployment/foo --to-revision=x`

are not having effect. I mean, the pods are replaced by new ones and a new revision is created which can be checked with

`kubectl rollout history deployment foo`

but when I call the service, the rollback had no effect.

I also tried to remove the `imagePullPolicy: Always`, guessing that it was always pulling even in the rollback, with no success because probably one thing is not related to the other.

---

Edited: The test is simple, I change the health check route of the http api to return something different in the json, and it doesn't.

---

Edited:

Maybe a typo, but not: I was executing with `... undo deployment/foo ...`, and now tried with `... undo deployment foo ...`. It also gives me `deployment.apps/foo rolled back`, but no changes in the live system.

More tests: I changed again my api route to test what would happen if I executed a rollout undo to every previous revision one by one. I applied the last 10 revisions, and nothing.

Comment: Without more details, how can you expect anyone to help you? How do you know it "had no effect"? What troubleshooting steps have you taken, and what were their outcomes?

Answer (score 3):

To be able to rollback to a previous version don't forget to append the **--record** parameter to your kubectl command, for example:

```
kubectl apply -f DEPLOYMENT.yaml --record
```

Then you should be able to see the history as you know with:

```
kubectl rollout history deployment DEPLOYMENT_NAME
```

And your rollback will work properly

```
kubectl rollout undo deployment DEPLOYMENT_NAME --to-revision=CHOOSEN_REVISION_NUMBER
```

Little example:

consider my nginx deployment manifest "nginx-test.yaml" here:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: nginx-deployment
  labels:
    app: nginx
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nginx
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nginx
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: nginx
        image: nginx
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
```

lets create it:

```
❯ kubectl apply -f nginx-test.yaml --record
Flag --record has been deprecated, --record will be removed in the future
deployment.apps/nginx-deployment created
```

lets check the image of this deployment, as expected from the manifest:

```
❯ k get pod nginx-deployment-74d589986c-k9whj -o yaml | grep image:
  - image: nginx
    image: docker.io/library/nginx:latest
```

now lets modify the image of this deployment to "nginx:1.21":

```
#"nginx=" correspond to the name of the container inside the pod create by the deployment.
❯ kubectl set image deploy nginx-deployment nginx=nginx:1.21.6
deployment.apps/nginx-deployment image updated
```

we can optionnaly check the rollout status:

```
❯ kubectl rollout status deployment nginx-deployment
deployment "nginx-deployment" successfully rolled out
```

we can check the rollout history with:

```
❯ kubectl rollout history deploy nginx-deployment
deployment.apps/nginx-deployment
REVISION  CHANGE-CAUSE
1         kubectl apply --filename=nginx-test.yaml --record=true
2         kubectl apply --filename=nginx-test.yaml --record=true
```

lets check the image of this deployment, as expected:

```
❯ k get pod nginx-deployment-66dcfc79b5-4pk7w -o yaml | grep image:
  - image: nginx:1.21.6
    image: docker.io/library/nginx:1.21.6
```

Oh, no, i don't like this image ! Lets rollback:

```
❯ kubectl rollout undo deployment nginx-deployment --to-revision=1
deployment.apps/nginx-deployment rolled back
```

creating:

```
> kubectl get pod -o wide
NAME                                    READY   STATUS              RESTARTS   AGE     IP           NODE                   NOMINATED NODE   READINESS GATES
pod/nginx-deployment-66dcfc79b5-4pk7w   1/1     Running             0          3m41s   10.244.3.4   so-cluster-1-worker3   <none>           <none>
pod/nginx-deployment-74d589986c-m2htr   0/1     ContainerCreating   0          13s     <none>       so-cluster-1-worker2   <none>           <none>
```

after few seconds:

```
NAME                                    READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE   IP            NODE                   NOMINATED NODE   READINESS GATES
pod/nginx-deployment-74d589986c-m2htr   1/1     Running   0          23s   10.244.4.10   so-cluster-1-worker2   <none>           <none>
```

as you can see it worked:

```
❯ k get pod nginx-deployment-74d589986c-m2htr -o yaml | grep image:
  - image: nginx
    image: docker.io/library/nginx:latest
```

lets recheck the history:

```
❯ kubectl rollout history deploy nginx-deployment
deployment.apps/nginx-deployment
REVISION  CHANGE-CAUSE
1         kubectl apply --filename=nginx-test.yaml --record=true
2         kubectl apply --filename=nginx-test.yaml --record=true
```

you can change the rollout history's CHANGE-CAUSE with the "kubernetes.io/change-cause" annotation:

```
❯ kubectl annotate deploy nginx-deployment kubernetes.io/change-cause="update image from 1.21.6 to latest" --reco
rd
Flag --record has been deprecated, --record will be removed in the future
deployment.apps/nginx-deployment annotated
```

lets recheck the history:

```
❯ kubectl rollout history deploy nginx-deployment
deployment.apps/nginx-deployment
REVISION  CHANGE-CAUSE
2         kubectl apply --filename=nginx-test.yaml --record=true
3         update image from 1.21.6 to latest
```

lets describe the deployment:

```
❯ kubectl describe deploy nginx-deploy
Name:                   nginx-deployment
Namespace:              so-tests
CreationTimestamp:      Fri, 06 May 2022 00:56:09 -0300
Labels:                 app=nginx
Annotations:            deployment.kubernetes.io/revision: 3
                        kubernetes.io/change-cause: update image from latest to latest
...
```

hope this has helped you, bguess.

Comment: Maybe the --record will do the trick, despite it's deprecation. I'll try and feedback here. The change-cause update is one thing that I was willing to know. Thanks!

Comment: Great keep us informed

Comment: I realized that my scenario gives me no choice of passing the --record param. The --record would have been passed in the manifest apply. But I have no changes to do in my manifest. I'm just restarting my rollout, and I cannot mess with the manifest because I'm doing it in prod. I will edit the post because I did some more tests.

Comment: @RafaelBarros you dont need to have changes to do in your manifest just execute the commande kubectl apply -f XXXX --record and it will be recorded... This is the answer to your question and there is no other answer....

Comment: I mean, if you have constraints that are linked to your environment its probably more interesting to create another question, but this question has been answered, it will help future users that needs to do rollbacks, thanks :D

Comment: I applied the --record without changing the manifest. Now the CHANGE-CAUSE is recorded with "kubectl apply --filename=deploy.yaml --record=true", but it did not change the fact that is not rolling back the live code.

Comment: now that you have record, Modify your manifest with the image of your choice for example (different of the current one) with the command: `kubectl set image deploy YOUR_DEPLOY_NAME YOUR_CONTAINER_NAME=YOUR_IMAGE_NAME:YOUR_TAG` and once this is done, you will see your new pods, and a new line in rollout history. from there if you want to rollback to the previous deployment with the old image, just execute `kubectl rollout undo deployment YOUR_DEPLOY_NAME --to-revision=YOUR_PREVIOUS_REVISION_NUMBER` and that should work, have you done exactly this steps?

Comment: I cannot change the image as i said because i'm in prod.

Comment: The rollback will work from the moment you added the --record flag, if you havent made any change between the record and the rollback there is not previous version to rollback now. If you are in production, I hope you keep your manifests in a VCS so you can retrieve them and redeploy them (this is the best practice)

Answer (score 1):

I experienced a similar situation and it was more an own mistake rather than a configuration issue with my K8s manifests.

At my Docker image creation workflow, I forgot to update the version of my Docker image. I have a GitHub Action workflow that pushes the image to DockerHub. Not updating the image version, overwrote the current image with latest changes in the application.

Then my `kubectl rollout undo` command was pulling the correct image but that image had the most recent changes in the application. In other words, image 1.1 was the same as 1.0. Running undo had no effect on the application state.

Stupid mistake but that was my experience in case helps someone.

Comment: I am thinking the problem might really be the versioning. I'm not tagging the releases. If k8s always pulls "latest", the undo would not work?